Read numbers under barcode (not barcode stripes itself) in .NET 8
I need help about reading numbers under barcode (not stripes) from PDF file. My idea was to convert page to image and then read it.
This is example of barcode that is located in the top right part of PDF document.
(https://i.sstatic.net/jtJl89rF.png)
I tried ZXing to try and read numbers under barcode, from image at least, but I had no luck.
 public static string ReadBarcodeFromImage(string filePath)
 {

     BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader()
     {
         AutoRotate = true,
         Options =
         {
             TryHarder = true,
             TryInverted = true,  
         }
     };

     var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filepath);
     var result = barcodeReader.Decode(bitmap);
     return result?.Text;
 }

Then I tried to convert pdf page to image, using PdfiumViewer, and read it but also had no luck:
public string ReadBarcodeFromPdf(string pdfPath)
{
        using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(pdfPath))
        {

            // Render the first page
            using (var image = document.Render(0, 300, 300, true))
            {
                //ZXing
                BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader()
                {
                    AutoRotate = true,
                    Options =
                    {
                        TryHarder = true,
                        TryInverted = true,
                    }
                };

                var result = barcodeReader.Decode((Bitmap)image);
                return result?.Text;
            }
        }
}

Code128C example

what you need is an OCR library not ZXing. ZXing will scan the barcode, but you want to read text. that there is a bar code on the smae page doesnt matter right?

Well yeah. It is usually page with some text but barcode and numbers under are always in the top right corner. Thanks for suggestion. I will trye some open source OCR to read it.

Unless somethings has gone very wrong, you should just be reading the barcode. The numbers below are just meant to be a human readable representation of the data contained in the barcode. If you're writing code, you should be using the computer readable representation, i.e. the barcode itself.

I had no luck. what's the barcode format? ZXing supports specific formats. You'll have to find a different library if the format isn't supported. Reading the digits is a lot harder than reading the barcode

@PanagiotisKanavos Format is Code39. My client said they put barcode on page, then scan it and save it in pdf format. Only problem is that they do not pay so much attention to how they put barcode sticker. It is not always straight and perfect.
This is the reason I want to read numbers under barcode.

Barcodes are never straight and perfect and yet they can be read even when numbers can't. That's the very reason they exist. A barcode scanner can read barcodes at an angle and even half at a time, and still recover the full barcode. It will work even if large parts of it are smudged or torn away. In your image the barcode is far larger than the numbers themselves

looking at what you shared. Just use ZXing. OCR will give you worse results. ZXing does what you are trying to.

I added new example. It is plain image with Code128C and no luck with scanning.
This option also did not gave me any results: PossibleFormats = new[] { BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 },

It looks like you are rendering the entire page at 300x300. Have you looked at the image  that you're asking ZXing to attempt to scan. Have you tried a higher resolution?

Your inputs are simply bad quality the first was a dummy so undetectable your second is so poor even a human is always going to be better than OCR.
As a Human I see the numbers easily. as 0000003531 but OCR simply is not that good at numbers without higher pixel contrast and density, the bar code is corrupted by scanning with anti-alias greyscale.

However with a good system the combination should function ?

When image quality is improved the code can be easily detected from a full size page.

For zxing the image will often need to be DE skewed and auto cropped before detection. This image was produced by https://github.com/galfar/deskew/releases
deskew32 -a 89 -b FFFFFF -r 5,5,2000,2000 test.png
Deskew 1.30 (2019-06-07) x86 by Marek Mauder
http://galfar.vevb.net/deskew/
Preparing input image (test.png [1654x2338/Index8]) ...
Calculating skew angle...
Skew angle found [deg]: 33.500
Rotating image...
Saving output (.....\out.png [2670x2863/R8G8B8]) ...
Done!



https://zxing.org/w/decode


Sorry I added low quality image. Now it is higher quality. The one I use in testing and still did not recognized barcode.

You can read the numbers with Tesseract, open source OCR library.
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html
Depending on the language model and parameters used, you may get slightly different results but if you are only expecting numbers as result you can parse/process further.
Below command line results are using your image as input.
ENG and DEU Fast language models are used. Fast, Normal, Best Models exist at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr
C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract "d:\temp\jtJl89rF.png" stdout --tessdata-dir "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata" --psm 3 -l eng
(0123456789

C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract "d:\temp\jtJl89rF.png" stdout --tessdata-dir "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata" --psm 3 -l deu
0123456789

Reminder.
I do not suggest that this is the best way. OCR is less reliable than reading Barcodes because barcodes have an internal checksum.
Tip # 1:
You mention you are converting your PDF to image first. If your PDF is vector (not a scanned file) I am fairly certain that extracting text and parsing the text result will give more accurate and faster result. If you are willing to share a representative PDF feel free
Tip # 2:
If you have control over the Barcode itself, prefer QR-Codes. ZXing library can detect and read QR-Codes much faster and reliable than 1 directional Barcodes like in your sample.

Thank you for you answer. I gave up with tesseract and now focusing on ZXing only. I added new example of Code128C wich is not recognized.
